# Is there a study that has been done showing the transformational power of the Holy Spirit in people's lives?

Tags: pneumatology, christian-living, reference-request

It's pretty clear that the Bible promises to change people's lives. It's also pretty clear that it did significantly change people's lives such as the apostles and others both in the the present day (e.g. Chuck Colson) and throughout history. My question is, has there ever been a study done to show the transformational power Christianity has in a person's life? It seems like a study such as that would provide significant evidence to support the claims of Christianity.

Comment: Welcome! Thanks for contributing. This is an interesting question, but you could make it more clear by specifying what kind of *transformation* you mean.  Obviously no study can measure the condition of the heart, so we are left with external behaviors.  Criminal recidivism rates? Hours of volunteer service? Hopefully you see how difficult it would be to quantify this.  If you haven't already done so, I hope you'll take a minute to take the [tour] and learn [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576).

Comment: The Bible tells us that "by their fruits you shall know them" (Matthew 7:16). Therefore, we should expect to find people who were producing wicked fruit before they were saved, and the fruit of the Spirit afterward. Therefore, criminal recidivism rates among among criminals who have gotten saved vs those who have not works probably be a good start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple answer to your question is **yes**, there are many such studies, and here is a good place to start looking for them:

[The Nature of Spiritual Transformation - A Review of the Literature, Prepared byArthur J. Schwartz, Ed.D.](http://www.metanexus.net/archive/spiritualtransformationresearch/research/pdf/STSRP-LiteratureReview2-7.PDF)